# Error using wget with subprocess to download tar file

Tags: subprocess, wget, using

I'm trying to use `wget` with subprocess to download a tar file.
In my Ide I enter `web_paage = subprocess.run('wget -O', web_dnld_file.tar url,capture=True)`
I have also tried `args = ['wget -O', web_dnld_file.tar url)`
The ide indicates error cannot assign to literal

Comment: `subprocess.run` is used python, if you use python please consider adding tag `python`, please also explain why did you use `using` tag which imply you are harnessing `using` keyword, which as far as I know is not present in neither `python` or `wget`.

Comment: This was my first post I'm using Python with wget